# Should i do authorization on my Domain Services?

Tags: c#, authorization, domain-driven-design

I have the following domain service:

```
pulic void DeleteCustomer(int customerId, string userIdentity, string userPassword)
{
    //1º Do login operation to verify if the credentials are valid.

    customerRepository.DeleteById(customerId);
}
```

Let's say that I am consuming this code of ASP.NET MVC or Windows Forms application that has a login window.

The login will be validated again in each operation, wasting resources.

Let's say I change it to:

```
pulic void DeleteCustomer (int customerId, int requestUserId)
{
    //1º Trust that requestUserId is valid.

    //Do something with the requestUserId (e.g Set the UserId that deleted the customer)

    customerRepository.DeleteById(customerId);
}
```

In this case, login operation will be made by the ASP.NET MVC OR Windows Forms Application just one time but any caller can pass any requestUserId, leaving a terrible security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to do authorization in any methods that need authorization otherwise there will be a security problem, especially when these methods are **entry points** in your backend logic. That means if you deploy these domain services as another tier which is accessible from outside, these methods **really need** protection.

From [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) perspective, every method should be able to defend itself from invalid or fake inputs which is also applicable in this case.

From [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) stateless perspective, every request should be **isolated** from each other which means each request should carry all the necessary information without relying on previous requests and **there even should not be a server state**. For that reason, all requests should be authorized independently.

Furthermore, authorization is a cross-cutting concern, you should consider writing your authorization code as an attribute.

Comment: Hi @Khanh TO. I agree with you about defensive programming perspective. 

In my case each authorization will query a database, that is, if you are consuming the service from an ASP.NET MVC the user will perform the login (First authorization). When the user invoke an action, this will another authorization. If this action calls five methods in the service, will be more five hits on the database to do the same authorization, will be 6 queries executed unnecessarily.

Comment: @Vinicius Gonçalves: with asp.net mvc you pointed out, the information about the logged-in user should be contain inside an encrypted ticket. When the server receives this ticket from the client, the server can decrypt to get the information without accessing the DB.

Comment: @Vinicius Gonçalves: In the case of authorization, I think we usually need to protect the `entry points` of backend service. If the entry points are asp.net mvc action methods, we may need to consider that. But if you deploy your domain services as another tier, these would become entry points and need protection.

Comment: So in an ASP.NET application, should I trust that the callers of the service will pass a valid userId?

Comment: @Vinicius Gonçalves: Is the caller in the same process of the domain service? and is the caller protected (if the caller is the entry point to your backend)?

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves: if you are considering calling your service from MVC layer, you should use either MVC's builtin Authentication/Authorization classes in `System.Web.Security` or make your own abstraction that you could use to ask for auth. information from your other layers.

Comment: @Vinicius Gonçalves: if your domain services are hidden behind mvc actions (your callers) and they are in the same process. I think you only need to do authorization for your mvc actions (entry points).

Comment: Yes @Khanh, is the same and is protected, until now. But if in the future I distribute these services will likely be by WCF. All services within the domain assembly are internals (I'm using InternalsVisibleTo to view these services in my MVC application). In the case of the WCF, there is a global entry point?

Comment: @Vinicius Gonçalves: there is nothing to do with `InternalsVisibleTo`. Entry points here I mean entry points `into your process`. If you distribute your domain services as another process and the client application can call these methods directly, you need authorization.

Comment: @ViniciusGonçalves: KhanhTo tries to address that if you are going to expose your API to other clients/callers, eg. from a WCF service, you need to guard all your API's public entry points, methods.

Comment: I understand the point now. Thank you so much for help me  Khanh TO, kayess

Comment: FYI, Domain services should be hidden behind application services.

Comment: I'm confused on what this answer is recommending. It sounds like it is saying that the OP should put authorization logic inside of his domain service layer methods. Then, it ends by saying this is a cross cutting concern. I agree it's a cross cutting concern, and as @plalx stated, the domain services should be hidden behind the application services. It seems that authorization should occur at the application service level.

Comment: @crush: it means that you can write your authorization logic as reusable units (attributes in c#) and then you can apply it anywhere you need authorization. In case you deploy as multiple services, you need to protect all your endpoints if possible. The cross cutting concern with attributes is just an additional suggestion to improve code reusability

Answer (score 3):

While I totally agree with the logic of @KhanhTO, I would extend this with, as this is your service layer, other than attribute, i would rather inject in an authorization services interface that would do the checks with the logged in user, eg. to see if that he has correct permissions associated to his credentials to execute the given command.

Comment: Hi Kayess,

On my real code i do that. but I'm not comfortable with regard to performance.